# Which would be faster for live searching, XML or SQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, xml

I have a webpage field where it shows results as you type. Currently I am using an XML file stored on the server as the source for these results. Would it be faster if I directly query the database as letters are being typed? What is the best way to accomplish this?

I am using PHP and AJAX with MS SQL Server. Thank you.

Comment: Hitting database for each character is not good idea.

Comment: Searching through an XML file is not very efficient but it will probably work okay for smaller websites. A table with an index should be very fast, and is much more scalable. You can optimize it further by not sending a request after every single key stroke, waiting until the user has stopped typing.

Comment: So benchmark it and find out for sure

Comment: You can store the XML data in SQL Server and query. For performance you can create index on XML columns to boost your searches on that tables

Answer (score 0):

XML files are just text files stored on your machine or another one; they need to be read, parsed and written to, and only your program can do that. They'are also really, really inefficient, because of their text nature: reading and parsing a text file is very slow, and modifying it is even worse.

XML files are good for storing configuration settings and passing data between different systems, but data storage and processing should definitely live in a proper DBMS.

Hope this suffice your query.

Answer (score 0):

A more scalable solution would be to use a de-normalized table to store the results. You can use a Memory Optimized table for this if you are using SQL Server 2014 or later.

To speed up the querying, you can also create a Natively Compiled Stored Procedure, but this also supports in SQL Server 2014 or later.

Further, try and build a Full Text Search Index over the search results so that if will speed up the querying as well as give more functionality.